# Cannot detect Metamask login using ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, web3js, metamask, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I’m a ClojureScript beginner and I am trying to connect my app to Metamask wallet.

In the past I successfully did it on a pure JS project with the following code:

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import detectEthereumProvider from "@metamask/detect-provider";

window.addEventListener("load", async function () {
    const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
    if (provider !== window.ethereum) {
        reject("Failed to connect");
    }
    await provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

    if (provider) {
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    }
})
```

So I’m trying to translate this into ClojureScript. Here is what I’ve started to do:

```
(ns token-stream.views
 (:require
  [re-frame.core :as re-frame]
  [web3 :as web3]
  ["@metamask/detect-provider" :as detectEthereumProvider]))

(detectEthereumProvider/detectEthereumProvider)
```

Any idea how I could translate the JS code?

Please note that I want to interop web3.js library (no use of cljs-web3).

Thanks

Comment: There's a guide on https://clojurescript.org/guides/promise-interop that covers most of what you need on the puppeteer example (promises, JS object interop) and you can look at the JS interop section of https://cljs.info/cheatsheet/ for the rest

Comment: In shadow-cljs with the npm web3 package available, this also works: `(:require [web3]) (def instance (web3. (.-givenProvider web3))) (def eth (.-eth instance))`. Check if ready like this: `(.requestAccounts eth)`.

Answer (score 0):

I used [`cljs-web3`](https://github.com/district0x/cljs-web3):

Deps:

```clj
[cljs-web3 "0.19.0-0-11"]
```

Code:

```clj
(require '[cljs-web3.core :as web3])
(require '[cljs-web3.eth :as web3.eth])

;; Create web3 instance from injected web3 (Mist / Metamask)
(web3/web3)

;; And then 

(def provides-web3?
  (boolean (aget js/window "web3")))

(def web3-instance js/web3
  #_(web3/create-web3 "http://localhost:8545/"))

(def network-type
  (case (web3/version-network web3-instance)
    "1" :local-development ; FIXME: same as main-net
    "2" :morden-network ; deprecated
    "3" :ropsten-network
    "4" :rinkeby-network
    "42" :kovan-network
    :unknown-network))

(println "account:" (first (web3.eth/accounts web3-instance)))
```